# “To think a simple” What does this idiom mean in English?

Tags: meaning

> **I thought a simple** "It's inappropriate" would have sufficed.

“To think a simple” What does this idiom mean in English?

Comment: You've read it wrong. It means, **I thought that [a simple "it's imappropriate"] would have sufficed**, meaning the phrase "it's inappropriate" is simple.

Answer (score 4):

You would never say "I thought a simple" by itself; the word *simple* here is part of a noun phrase.

The sentence is basically

> I thought (noun phrase) would have sufficed.

In the noun phrase, the adjective *simple* is used to modify the noun.  The author is using the reported speech "It's inappropriate" as the noun, and *simple* modifies it.  You could think of it like

> I thought that **a simple statement of "it's inappropriate"** would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

*"It's inappropriate"* is the subject.

*"It's inappropriate" would have sufficed.* (Something else was actually said, but this would have been enough.)

*A simple "It's inappropriate" would have sufficed.* (Adds an adjective to "It's inappropriate", stating it's a simple phrase, so presumably something much longer was actually said.)

*I thought a simple "It's inappropriate" would have sufficed.*

Or, *I thought that a simple "It's inappropriate" would have sufficed.*

(In my opinion, this simple phrase would have been enough to say.)